# How to get the spark driver metrics json?

Tags: json, driver, apache-spark, metrics

I followed the monitoring guide : 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html
to configure the metricsservlet, but it seems this doc did not say anything useful...

And the commons in metrics.properties say:

"5. MetricsServlet is added by default as a sink in master, worker and client 
    driver, you can send http request "/metrics/json" to get a snapshot of all the 
    registered metrics in json format. For master, requests "/metrics/master/json" and 
    "/metrics/applications/json" can be sent seperately to get metrics snapshot of 
    instance master and applications. MetricsServlet may not be configured by self. 
"

but what is the prefix of the http request url? where should I submit the http request?

http://driver-node:4040/metrics/json
does not response with a json, just redirect to the web UI...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Spark 1.2.0, the metrics servlet is known to be broken due to an initialization ordering bug in SparkContext ([SPARK-4549](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4595); this is one of the few known 1.1.1 -> 1.2.0 regressions and is documented in the release notes).  There's a patch available to fix this issue (https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3444) and it will be included in Spark 1.2.1.  We're expected to begin voting on a 1.2.1 release candidate in the next week or so, so you can expect a maintenance release that includes this fix pretty soon.  In the meantime, you can build Spark yourself from the `master` or `branch-1.2` branches or use an earlier version of Spark (e.g. Spark 1.1.1) which does not have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Josh. When I hit the url /metrics/json, I get very few metrics. Is there a way I can get almost all the metrics that is exposed by the web UI ? TIA.